# How do you assign value to individual choices

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list-form, calculated-column-formula

Using: SharePoint Online

**How do you assign value to the following choices**

Low = 1
Medium = 2
high = 3

[image]

Then later on I want to be able to calculate 5 different questions for the total risk rating.

> Add 5 scores above together and divide by 5.  Score 5-7 = Low; 8-11 =
>   Medium; 12-15 = High

### But I'm not even given the option of picking those columns

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:  (the columns are assumed to named Q1,Q2, etc)

If a divide by 5 really works in your example (I don't think it will):

```
=CHOOSE(
INT(
  IF( Q1="Low", 1, IF( Q1="Medium", 2, IF( Q1="High", 3, 0) ) )
 +IF( Q2="Low", 1, IF( Q2="Medium", 2, IF( Q2="High", 3, 0) ) )  
 +IF( Q3="Low", 1, IF( Q3="Medium", 2, IF( Q3="High", 3, 0) ) )  
 +IF( Q4="Low", 1, IF( Q4="Medium", 2, IF( Q4="High", 3, 0) ) )  
 +IF( Q5="Low", 1, IF( Q5="Medium", 2, IF( Q5="High", 3, 0) ) )  
/ 5 ),
"Low","Medium", "High"
```

Otherwise:

```
=CHOOSE(
  IF( Q1="Low", 1, IF( Q1="Medium", 2, IF( Q1="High", 3, 0) ) )
 +IF( Q2="Low", 1, IF( Q2="Medium", 2, IF( Q2="High", 3, 0) ) )  
 +IF( Q3="Low", 1, IF( Q3="Medium", 2, IF( Q3="High", 3, 0) ) )  
 +IF( Q4="Low", 1, IF( Q4="Medium", 2, IF( Q4="High", 3, 0) ) )  
 +IF( Q5="Low", 1, IF( Q5="Medium", 2, IF( Q5="High", 3, 0) ) )  
+ 1, "","","","","","Low","Low","Low","Medium","Medium","Medium","Medium", "High", "High", "High", "High")
```

- One was added because CHOOSE does not work with zero as an index.
- The first "" is for zero (all Q's blank)
- The next ""'s are for if any of the five questions are blank.
- Three "low" for 5,6,7
- Four "medium" for 8,9,10,11
- Four "High" for 12,13,14,15

Comment: Helpful, but now I'm running into new issue. I added it to my original post.

Comment: Your screen capture shows that these are "radio buttons", and these should show up for Calculated Columns. If they are "Checkboxes (allow multiple selections)", then they will not show up. I just confirmed that they show up when adding a new Calculated Column using the browser and using SharePoint Designer.